# How to redirect without changing page with render web page

Tags: php, html

I have index page which include rednedpage.php and I need to know how to redirect to page without changing current page.

For example:
I am on page www.example.com/page
and I need to redirect user to www.example.com/page/login.php
but I want to user just see www.example.com/page

How can I do that?

Comment: `header( "refresh:1;url=/page/login.php" );` will redirect after 1 sec

Comment: if you want the user to see www.example.com/page but with the content of www.example.com/page/login.php you need to use `htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

Try write this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/login.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page [P]
```

It may be shortened:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?page/login.php.* /page [P]
```

But, if you dont want users to see .php file names in url, I recommend you to build site routing.
https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html

In case you dont need to refresh the page and include some content, for example login form, look in the direction of asynchronus technologies like 'Ajax'.